# ServiceStack JSONSerializer and HashSet<x>

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, servicestack

We have this code:

```
// using ServiceStack JSONSerializer
string typeInfoString = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString<Type>(typeof(HashSet<string>));
// yields "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[System.String, mscorlib]], System.Core"

// this string is the same thing, so it's probably valid json
string jsonTypeInfo = typeof(HashSet<string>).ToJson();

// this should work, I feel like
Type desType = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Type>(jsonTypeInfo);
// but desType ends up being null :(
```

Is there some ServiceStack gotcha about the HashSet type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in ServiceStack.Text. I have traced the problem to AssemblyTypeDefinition.cs line 17 (at the time of this writing). The incoming typeDefinition is "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[System.String, mscorlib]], System.Core" and the TypeDefinitionSeperator is ',' causing the string to be broken at the first instance of ',' instead of the second, where it should. Simulating the string being split properly (in the debugger) returns the proper result from your code.

You might want to submit this as a bug to the ServiceStack community.

Answer (score 3):

While this isn't the greatest answer, you can sort of get around this by creating a local class that inherits from HashSet.

Example:

```
public class HashSetHack<T> : HashSet<T> { }
```

Then refer to HashSetHack instead of HashSet, and it appears to work.